# Expressing a set using set-builder notation and then the simplifying the resulting expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Describe $ (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) $ in set-builder notation, and simplify it using the laws of logic.

So, looking at this intuitively, I know that it translates to “all elements contained in $ A $ but not $ B $, as well as all elements contained in both $ A $ and $ B $”. In other words, this is just $ A $. I can thus write out a variation of set-builder notation:
$$
\{ x \mid ((x \in A) \land \neg (x \in B)) \lor ((x \in A) \land (x \in B)) \}.
$$
This *does* allow me to use logical laws to simplify the problem, but it doesn’t look like examples of set-builder notation that I’ve seen and I feel like I’m missing a step. Would anyone be able to tell me how to convert what I’ve done so far into formal set-builder notation, while keeping the logical operators needed to simplify it?

Comment: It is cumbersome, but correct; the syntax of set-builder is $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ where $\varphi$ is a formula with $x$ free. And the long expression is a formula $\varphi(x,A,B)$ with $x$ free and two "parameters" $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Cumbersome is fine, I deliberately wrote it long-form so I'd have more to work with when simplifying. But you're saying that what I have written DOES qualify as a completed set-builder conversion?

Comment: Now you have to simplify the formula using [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: Yes, and I know the goal is to end up with A. Thank you for the help! If you make your comment an answer I can approve it.